# ¿Se puede colocar la ayuda del Spring Framework en Español?

Tags: java, spring, eclipse

Estoy empezando a aprender Spring y queria saber si existe una forma de habilitar la ayuda el spring framework en español, puntualmente me refiero a los textos de ayuda que aparecen al pasar el cursor por encima de un objeto del framework como en la imagen:

[image: Spring Boot STS]

No se si existira un plugin para hacerlo, quizas una traducción oficial de la comunidad o quizas se puede activar en el mismo IDE, estoy usando el Spring Tool Suite 4, soy casi nuevo con el eclipse. Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

La documentación de Spring que se ve en Eclipse es lo que se llama *JavaDoc*, [generada automáticamente](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.2.0.M3/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ModelAttribute.html) desde el [código fuente original](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ModelAttribute.java). Traducir el API sería complicado porque es HTML generado por el compilador y se regenera para cada versión, por lo que se necesitaría un gran esfuerzo para, en cada *commit* en el repositorio, se traduzcan todos los comentarios del código.

Las opciones que tienes es [visitar la documentación](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.2.0.M3/javadoc-api/) con un navegador como Chrome, que te ofrece una traducción automática bastante decente, o aprender inglés lo suficiente como para poder entender textos técnicos, que no es demasiado complicado.